# fprintf not writing to file, despite fclose()

Tags: c, getopt, fclose

As the title states I'm trying to write to a file with fprintf, and I've searched on Stack Overflow for why it wouldn't be writing to file. What I've found is that it holds it in memory until you close the file(right?), hence the usage of fclose(). However, it's still not working for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void printHelp()
{
    printf("Usage: fstring [ char ] [ amount ] Optional:[ outfile ]\n"
           "Example: fstring A 100 out.txt\n");
    exit(1);
}

char *f_string(const char *s, int t)
{
    int i; char *dst = malloc(t * strlen(s) + 1);
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        strcat(dst, s);
    }
    return dst;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c; char *file;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
        switch(c) {
        case 'f':
            file = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            printHelp();
            return 1;
        }

    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("You need at least two arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *res = f_string(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "w+");
    if(!f) {
        puts(res);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        fprintf(f, "%s", res);
    }

    fclose(f);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

What I really don't understand is why the above code doesn't work, but this does just fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[80];

    if(argc != 6) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You need to give 5 arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *in;
    if(!(in = fopen("spooky.csv", "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File %s doesn't exist!", in);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file1 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[4], "w");
    FILE *file3 = fopen(argv[5], "w");

    while(fscanf(in, "%79s", line) == 1) {
        if(strstr(line, argv[1]))
            fprintf(file1, "%s\n", line);
        else if (strstr(line, argv[3]))
            fprintf(file2, "%s\n", line);
        else
            fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

The second code works just fine writing to files. Hoping someone can enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: which input arguments are you using? And always check if malloc fails:
`if(!dst){ handle error }`

Comment: File writing is working fine for me. But what are you trying to write into file?

Comment: you could try using `fflush(f)` after `fprintf`

Comment: you need to initialize you allocated memory to 0x00 using `memset`, since `dst` can be containing anything, and `strcat` will try to find the 1st null byte to append/concatenate.

Comment: it is an essential skill to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [optind](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) to find out where non-optional arguments start.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c; char *file;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
        switch(c) {
        case 'f':
            file = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            printHelp();
            return 1;
        }


    int index = optind;
    if(argc - index + 1 < 3) {
        printf("You need at least two arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *res = f_string(argv[index], atoi(argv[index + 1]));
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "w+");
    if(!f) {
        puts(res);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        fprintf(f, "%s", res);
    }

    fclose(f);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is that the arguments are messed up.

After you called `getopt`, the point to arguments `argv` has been manipulated and no more pointed to the original argument. So afterwards when you use `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` for `fstring` function, they are not the arguments you passed to the main function.

The simplest correction is to store the arguments in temporary variables before passing `argv` to `getopt`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c; char *file;

    char *v1 = argv[1];
    int v2 = atoi(argv[2]);


    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
        switch(c) {
        case 'f':
            file = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            printHelp();
            return 1;
        }

    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("You need at least two arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *res = f_string(v1, v2);
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "w+");
    if(!f) {
        puts(res);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        fprintf(f, "%s", res);
    }

    fclose(f);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From man page of `getopt()`: *By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end*.

If your call your executable with options `Abc 10 -f out.txt` then after `getopt` processing `argv[1]` will be `-f` and `argv[2]` will be `out.txt`. So you have to change line

```
char *res = f_string(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
```

to

```
char *res = f_string(argv[3], atoi(argv[4]));
```

Otherwise, help usage is completely wrong because according to code nothing is optional.

Function `f_string()` has to be corrected:

```
char *f_string(const char *s, int t)
{
    int i; 
    char *dst = malloc(t * strlen(s) + 1);
    dst[0] = '\0';  // <-----

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        strcat(dst, s);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Without proper initialization `strcat()` could start at the middle of `dst`.